# Save navbar height to redux from different components

Tags: reactjs, redux, height, navbar

I am a new react user. I have been struggling with a task like this for a few days. I have a project that contains many components and redux. We also have a navbar that uses react-headroom. I need to add the height of that navbar to react-redux and update it when I switch to another component, so that I can set the margin-top for the content of that view based on that. Currently the navbar is obscuring the content of my view. How can I make this happen? Could someone please write me some simple, makeshift code of what this would look like? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Some views in the app have an additional bar with information. On one view this bar may be longer on another shorter. I would like the content in the component to be offset from the top by a given navbar height (for the moment). I thought of storing the navbar height in redux, and somehow, when switching between components, check the height and update the margin-top for the content.

Unfortunately, I am correcting this after someone, the navbar is fixed, and we cannot change it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK, content has been edited.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still way too abstract to give you detailed advice. What does "navbar is fixed" mean? Is this a component you cannot touch? Are you in control of rendering it, if so how? General advice though: you don't need to use redux for this. If the height of one element dictates a css property of another element, you should abstract this away. For example by putting both the navbar and the content container in another element that sets the margin top.

Comment: This means that the navbar has position fixed. The navbar is in a separate element. Because it is fixed it does not affect the content on the page. At the bottom of the navbar there is an alert bar which is sometimes very high and it obscures the content when you are at the top of the page. There are many components with the content and the navbar is one. I want all components to know about this height and be able to set appropriate distance from the top of the page when this element is high.